# Lumen route not working

Tags: lumen

Here is my route:

```
$router->get('/{any:/^(?!(?:api*|auth*|images*)).*/}', 'HomeController@index');
```

I dont want it match any route start with api, auth, images. But when i try visit my site: http://example.com it's return Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
And i try visit site start with api, auth, images it's still can access. What happen with my route? I dont think my regexr is wrong